# Copying list item to clipboard issue

Tags: android, arrays, web-services, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I am working on a project where I need to put some plain text to clipboard but the problem is when I try to paste it somewhere. I tried to resolve but in vain. It appears as the next item of the same list. I am using customArrayadapter. Code for my adapter is given below:

```
package com.gippy.status99;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;


import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.ClipboardManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class StatusAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<StatusEntity> {
Context context;String copytext;int id;
    public StatusAdapter(Context context, int resource,
            int textViewResourceId, List<StatusEntity> objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.status_list_item,parent,false);

        TextView txtCategory=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_status);
        Button  btn_copy=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_btn_copy);
        Button  btn_share=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_btn_share);

        StatusEntity obj=getItem(position); 
        txtCategory.setText(obj.getStatus());
        id=obj.getStatusid();

        copytext=txtCategory.getText().toString();
        btn_copy.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             ClipboardManager clipmanager=(ClipboardManager)getContext().getSystemService(getContext().CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
             ClipData clip=ClipData.newPlainText("data",copytext);
             Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Copied to clipboard::::"+position+"---"+id, 1000).show();
             clipmanager.setPrimaryClip(clip);
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
    }
```

[image]

Now if i will try to copy status i.e. I copied first item but when i its second item is pasted. How to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position variable in getView() contains the position information requested by the control to display stuff. When the user interact with the button on a row, the getView() doesn't get called. Therefore, save the position value in tag field in your btn_copy object. Change the getView() like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Only create view if convertView is null
    if(convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.status_list_item,parent,false);

        Button  btn_copy=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_btn_copy);
        btn_copy.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
            // Get the saved position
            int pos = (int)v.getTag();
            StatusEntity obj=getItem(pos);
            ClipboardManager clipmanager= (ClipboardManager)getContext().getSystemService(getContext().CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            ClipData clip=ClipData.newPlainText("data",obj.getStatus());
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Copied to clipboard::::"+pos+"---"+obj.getStatusid(), 1000).show();
            clipmanager.setPrimaryClip(clip);
          }
        });
    }

    TextView txtCategory=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_status);
    Button  btn_copy=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_btn_copy);
    Button  btn_share=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_btn_share);

    // Save the position for use in the copy button
    btn_copy.setTag(position);

    StatusEntity obj=getItem(position); 
    txtCategory.setText(obj.getStatus());


    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Its working thanx.......can you please help me in implementing share button too.....i have implemented but getting error....

Comment: What was the error? To share some text, use the following intent: Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, obj.getStatus());
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);

Comment: I have used the same and it is working pretty fine on whatsapp but if i try to share on facebook ,it shows blank.